# Deployment of postgresql on AWS EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture

I am new to architecture role.  There is a requirement to read file from S3 and load into postgresql in AWS EC2 instance.  As per the role I need to share the deployment model for this.   Could anyone guide what details I need to provide?

Answer (score 0):

This will require a few components:

Assuming **python3,** you will need to get the **DataBase credentials** to connect-
This will be via [pyscopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)

In the same script, you will need to connect to the AWS S3 bucket using [AWS SDK](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/), read the file into a variable, and simply execute a query in order to update/insert the file into the DB.

you can refer to this article It might provide some insights-
[AWS Serverless Hit n’ Run](https://towardsdatascience.com/aws-serverless-hit-n-run-5dcc0deb586e)

Answer (score 0):

You can use postgres COPY command to do your task. Overview of the command can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> Install `Postgre SQL on EC2`, simple documentation can be found [here](https://dailyscrawl.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-amazon-linux-2/).
>
> Install and configure `AWS CLI in EC2` (if its not there by deafult)
>
> Use `AWS S3 sync` or `AWS S3 cp` commmands to download files from S3 to your local directory
>
> Use `psql \COPY` command to copy the files into your database

Example like below

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/psql.csv /myfolder/psql.csv
psql -h localhost -U username -d dbname -c '\COPY table FROM ''psql.csv'' CSV HEADER'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Hope we can write this piece of code in a shell script and run.